# SED: How to search for word "tokens" on consecutive lines (Windows)?

Tags: regex, windows, awk, sed

I have EDI files I need to find, by using SED to search for some anomalies.

The anomaly is when I search for a "token" called `SGP`, and where they are on multiple consecutive lines — so one SGP on one line and another SGP on another line — regardless of what's after the token:

```
SGP+SEGU1037087'
SGP+DFSU1143210'
SGP+SEGU1166926'
SGP+TGHU1203545'
```

But I don't want to find files where there are other segment lines between each SGP line:

```
SGP+TGHU1643436'
GID+2+3:BAG'
FTX+AAA+++sdfjkhsdfjkhsdfjkh'
MEA+AAE+AAB+KGM:20000.0000'
MEA+AAE+AAW+MTQ:.0000'
SGP+HCIU2090577'
```

So I've tried this:

```
sed 'SGP.*\n.*SGP' < *.txt
```

And as probably expected, I get nothing.

Any ideas on how to feed into SED a list of files in DOS, and get a list of files that meet the above criteria?

**UPDATE**

I think I have the "feed the files" bit here. But I am still stuck on how to use SED properly.

```
for i in *.txt; do
    sed -i '<<WHAT DO I PLACE HERE?>>' $i
done
```

**UPDATE 2**

Please no Unix/Bash/etc solutions.. I am in Windows only! Thank you

**UPDATE 3**

Tried a DOS equivalent of @tshiono's answer but I get nothing..

```
for %%f in (*.txt) do (
    sed -ne ':l;N;$!b l;/SGP[^\n]\+\nSGP/p' %%f
}
```

**UPDATE 4**
@tshiono - I want the script to find files that have this pattern...

```
SGP+SEGU1037087'
SGP+DFSU1143210'
SGP+SEGU1166926'
SGP+TGHU1203545'
```

Not this pattern ...

```
SGP+SEGU1037087'
FTT+asdjkfhsdkf hsdjkfh sdfjkh sdf
FTX+f sdfjsdfkljsdkfljsdklfj
GID+sdfjkhsdjkfhsdjkfsdf
SGP+DFSU1143210'
FTT+asdjkfhsdkf hsdjkfh sdfjkh sdf
FTX+f sdfjsdfkljsdkfljsdklfj
GID+sdfjkhsdjkfhsdjkfsdf
SGP+SEGU1166926'
FTT+asdjkfhsdkf hsdjkfh sdfjkh sdf
FTX+f sdfjsdfkljsdkfljsdklfj
GID+sdfjkhsdjkfhsdjkfsdf
SGP+TGHU1203545'
```

Again - **only** lines with SGP as a token on every NEWLINE

Comment: `grep` is what you need to list files matching a regex, but unfortunately it isn't suited for multiline matching.. if you install `ripgrep`, you can do `rg -lU 'SGP.*\n.*SGP' *.txt`

Comment: if you have perl, you can use `perl -0777 -ne 'print "$ARGV\n" and close ARGV if /SGP.*\n.*SGP/' *.txt`

Comment: Suppose there are three non-SGP lines at the start of the file, then 4 consecutive SGP lines, and then 3 more non-SGP lines.  Is a file like that meant to be selected or rejected?  When a file is selected, do you need the contents or the file name?  Do you need to be able to tell which file a given sequence of SGP lines comes from?  What if a file contains only a single SGP line?  There are ways to do it — even with `sed` though `awk` or Perl or Python would be simpler.  From the examples, it appears that the `SGP` must appear at the bei=ginning of a line to count.

Comment: Also, suppose there was an extra SGP line at the end of your second sample data; would you then need to see that file because there are adjacent SGP lines?  Or is it only a problem if all the lines are SGP lines?  And do you need to see the whole file, or only the part where there are adjacent SGP lines?

Comment: @anubhava - that would never happen. EDI files have mandatory structures. Thanks anyway

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - any files that have SGP lines consecutively more than once, must be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requirement is to detect which files contain consecutive lines both starting `SGP`.

Using standard (POSIX) [`sed`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html), there's no way to get `sed` to print the file name.  You can use this combination of shell script and `sed`, though, to detect which files contain consecutive lines starting with `SGP`:

```
for file in *.txt;
do
    if [ -n "$(sed -n -e '/^SGP/{N;/^SGP.*\nSGP/{p;q;}}' "$file")" ]
    then echo "$file"
    fi
done
```

The shell test `[ … ]` checks whether the output of `$(sed …)` is a non-empty string, and reports the name of the file if it is.  Note that the script is more flexible if, instead of using the glob `*.txt`, it uses the `"$@"` (list of arguments, preserving spaces etc).  You can the write:

```
sh find-consecutive-SGP.sh *.txt
```

or use other more fanciful ways of specifying the file names as arguments.

The `sed` command doesn't print by default (`-n`).  It looks for a line starting `SGP` and appends the next line into the 'pattern space'.  It then looks to see if the result has two lots of `SGP` in it; one at the start (we know that will be there) and one after a newline.  If that's found, it prints both lines (the pattern space) and quits because its job is done; it has found two consecutive lines both starting `SGP`.  If the pattern space doesn't match, it is not printed (because of the `-n`) and more data is read.  Any lines that don't start `SGP` are ignored and not printed.

With GNU `sed`, the `F` command prints the file name and a newline, so you could use:

```
for file in *.txt;
do
    sed -n -e '/^SGP/{N;/^SGP.*\nSGP/{F;q;}}' "$file"
done
```

AFAICT from the GNU [`sed` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html), there's no way to 'skip to the start of the next file' so you have to test each file separately as shown, rather than trying `sed -n -e '…' *.txt` — that will only report the first file that breaches the condition, not all the files.

Comment: How do I do this in Windows DOS? I asked for a Windows solution please, not Unix

Comment: Install Cygwin and use that?  The `sed` command should work fine with any Windows version of `sed`. I'm using the shell script for your 'update' as the main basis for what you want. If that doesn't work on DOS, why did you show it? The DOS BAT or CMD system probably handles quotes differently. In case of doubt, put the `sed` script into a file `double-sgp.sed` and use `sed -n -f double-sgp.sed "$file"` (double quotes perhaps optional) or the BAT equivalent to run the `sed` script. If you can't capture output in a  BAT file, it's time to go home (or use GNU `sed` with the `F` command).

Comment: Also, if you're in Windows, use PowerShell.  But you want a `sed` solution; that's a Unix-style command.  Your requirements are unusual!  You want a Windows solution (so no shell) but you can use `sed` (a Unix and not primarily a Windows command). Why not use the Linux subsystem on WIndows.  Or are you working with antique versions of Windows?  Have fun!  I gave up on DOS in about 1985 — it annoyed me too much back then — and haven't used WIndows seriously (ditto — though it has improved a bit over the years).

Comment: Thank you for your solution, but I was referring to "sed" as I was trying to find the answer using Unix commands in Windows, as you said DOS does these things very poorly. I could have referred to grep or any other search tool, primarily written for Unix, but in my case - had to be used in a Windows environment. Anyway, perhaps I've misled everyone with my OP, in that I was referring to SED. But what other Windows command could do the same as SED? Thank you anyway. I appreciate your responses.

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
FNR==1{
  if(count){
    if(fnr==count){
        print prev_file " has all lines of SGP."
    }
  }
  prev_file=FILENAME
  count=fnr=""
}
/^SGP/{
  ++count
}
{
  fnr++
}
END{
  if(fnr==count){
    print prev_file " has all lines of SGP."
  }
}
' *.txt
```

Comment: Windows only please!

Comment: @Fandango68, so it didn't work on it for you? I apologies I don't have `awk` on windows systems.

Answer (score 1):

If your objective is to get the list of *filenames* which meet the criteria,
how about:

```
for i in *.txt; do
    [[ -n $(sed -ne ':l;N;$!b l;/SGP[^\n]\+\nSGP/p' "$i") ]] && echo "$i"
done
```

- The `sed` commands `:l;N;$!b` makes a loop and slurps the whole lines
  in the pattern space including "\n"
- Then it matches the lines with the pattern of two consecutive lines
  which both contain `SGP`.
- If the `sed` output is non-empty, it prints the current filename.

**[Update]**

If your requirement is DOS platform, please try instead:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for %%f in (text*.txt) do (
    set result=
    for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in (`sed.exe -ne ":l;N;$!b l;/SGP.\+\nSGP.\+/p" %%f`) do set result=!result!%%a
    if "!result!" neq "" (
        echo %%f
    ) 
)
```

I've tested with Windows10 and sed-4.2.1.

Comment: with GNU sed you can do: `for f in *.txt; do sed -n '/SGP/{n; /SGP/{F; q}}' "$f"; done`

Comment: @Sundeep thank you for the informative comment. It helps me a lot.

Comment: Is this for Windows, like I asked in the OP? I ran it and I get "i was unexpected at this time." error

Comment: @Fandango68 Thank you for the feedback. Your code `for i in *.txt; ...` has a shell (sh, bash etc.) syntax and I had assumed it runs in your Windows environment. But the error message `i was unexpected at this time.` looks like that of DOS batch file (*.bat). Do you prefer a solution with `bat` file?

Comment: @tshiono my apologies for late reply. Yes please! Thank you

Comment: @Fandango68 thank you for the feedback. I've updated my answer with a DOS version. Hope it helps.

Comment: @tshiono unfortunately it didn't work. File with SGP starting on line line, and other guff on subsequent lines before another SGP starts on another line, have been found. I need this to only find where the SGP token appears at the start of the line and the NEXT LINE also has SGP. So files with at least TWO lines that have SGP starting on a NEW LINE. I hope that's not confusing. I've updated my OP

Comment: @Fandango68 thank you for the feedback, but it works with your files in the update4 as expected; it finds the first file only in my environment. I cannot figure out the difference with your environment.